# JMETER ERROR: {"errorcode":9999,"errormessage":"Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0"}

Tags: debugging, jmeter, performance-testing, remote-debugging

I am running a test and on running it after co-relating sessionid, I am getting the following below error in "response data" tab in "view results tree listener".

Can you please help me fix this error:

Sampler Result:

```
Thread Name: Xaas_No 1-1
Sample Start: 2018-06-14 14:57:20 IST
Load time: 1731
Connect Time: 1255
Latency: 1730
Size in bytes: 852
Sent bytes:957
Headers size in bytes: 776
Body size in bytes: 76
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 500
Response message: Internal Server Error

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
x-powered-by: Express
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
content-length: 76
etag: W/"4c-gdbCiVcDg5gx+63/uawAq4eRIu0"
date: Thu, 14 Jun 2018 09:27:12 GMT
connection: close
Set-Cookie: BIGipServeriapxaasbotbuildertest.accenture.com-443=1932329994.47873.0000;Path=/;Version=1;Secure;Httponly
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' *.accenture.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src 'self' *.accenture.com data:; connect-src 'self' *.accenture.com *.dialogflow.com
Cache-Control: private; max-age=31536000
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;includeSubDomains
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: application/json; charset=utf-8
DataEncoding: utf-8
```

Request:

POST https://iapxaasbotbuildertest.accenture.com/channelService/channelWeb/619e81efe7

POST data:

```
%7B%22entry%22%3A%5B%7B%22sessionid%22%3A%22%22%2C%22tenantid%22%3A%22619e81efe7%22%2C%22botid%22%3A%229bb95dfba0%22%2C%22channel%22%3A%22Web%22%2C%22messaging%22%3A%5B%7B%22message%22%3A%7B%22messageId%22%3A123%2C%22text%22%3A%22hi%22%2C%22timestamp%22%3A1528967999992%7D%2C%22sender%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22USR12%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22sylvin%22%7D%7D%5D%7D%5D%7D=
```

[no cookies]

```
Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: https://iapxaasbotbuildertest.accenture.com
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Referer: https://iapxaasbotbuildertest.accenture.com/demo/webtest/?tenantID=619e81efe7&botID=9bb95dfba0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36 managedpc (Accenture)
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 362
Host: iapxaasbotbuildertest.accenture.com
```

Response data:

> {   "errorcode": 9999,   "errormessage": "Unexpected token % in JSON
>   at position 0" }

Answer (score 0):

You should not be encoding your [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) payload, it should go **as it is**

So make sure to **uncheck** "Encode" box in your [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

[image: JMeter JSON Encode]

Also make sure to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan as you seem to be receiving some cookies but not sending them back.

See [REST API Testing - How to Do it Right](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/rest-api-testing-how-to-do-it-right) article for more information if needed.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, thanks for your response. "Encode" box in HTTP Request sampler is unchecked and cookie manager is also there.But still I am getting Error 500, with this error msg in response data: {"errorcode":9999,"errormessage":"Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0"}